# Is there "UNDO" for a mysql update?

Tags: mysql

I was updating a database. I tried on live databse. it works actually but update more rows than expected. I want to be certain about what happened.

Comment: There was a tiny tear in the space-time continuum. There is no UNDO.

Comment: You could have done it if you started a transaction - it's possible to roll it back until it is committed. However, once committed, there is no way back except for restoring data from backup

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately `NO`; there's `ROLLBACK` command in MySql which let you undo the latest operation, but once you committed once, it is not possible rollback the committed changes..

> However, if an error occurs during statement execution, the statement is rolled back.

Check [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/commit.html) for more information.

Meanwhile, you need to do some extra-work, you can delete those rows which are added by mistake.

Comment: There is indeed a rollback command, which will undo all of the current transaction.  But once the transaction is committed, it can no longer be rolled back.

Comment: thanks .. i edited my answer. i was not aware ,